# Is it possible to rotate text in jsreport when using the chrome-pdf recipe?

Tags: jsreport

I am trying to create a report in jsreport and I need to put some rotated text the margin (basically on the left).

I've created a table, 1 row hight 2 columns wide, put everything I need on the main page in the left right column and the small amount of text I need to be rotated in the left column.  The left column has a class that uses a style that defines the write-mode as vertical-lr.

If I run this as an HTML recipe it works perfectly, if I use the chrome-pdf engine the left text remains in the normal orientation.

I have tried using transform rather than write-mode in the style definition - no difference.

Thanks in advance